# Swipe functionality working locally but fails on device farm

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I am trying to run a simple swipe function for an iOS app. The swipe functionality that I'm using is something like this:

```
 public static void swipe (AppiumDriver<?> driver, WebElement element, String direction ) throws Exception {
    int startX = element.getLocation().getX();
    int startY = element.getLocation().getY();
    int endX = element.getLocation().getX();
    int endY=element.getLocation().getY();

    switch (direction){
    case  "left":
        System.out.println(startX);
        startX += element.getSize().getWidth();
        endX = -(element.getSize().getWidth());
        break;
    case "right":
        startX = 0;
        endX +=element.getSize().getWidth();
        break;
    case "up":
        startY += element.getSize().getHeight();
        endY =  -element.getSize().getHeight();
        break;
    case "down":
        endY += driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("invalid direction, must be left/right/up/down");
    }
    //driver.swipe(startX, startY, endX, endY, 1000);
 new TouchAction(driver).press(startX, startY).waitAction(1000).moveTo(endX, 
       endY).release().perform();
    System.out.println(startX +" " + startY+ " " + endX+ " " +endY);

}
```

The default capabilities I'm using locally are:

```
"platformName": "iOS"
"platformVersion": "10.3"
"automationName": "Appium"
"deviceName": "iPhone 7"
```

*I have tried with the same desired capabilities locally and its working fine on the simulator. I am running it on the same device(i in the device farm.*

I am also using the **Appium v1.6.5** locally as well as in device farm.

Answer (score 2):

Do not set your desired capabilities for device farm.  It will not use them and in expected things happen when doing that.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app/blob/master/src/test/java/Tests/AbstractBaseTests/TestBase.java#L60

Try not setting them and see if that helps.  Let me know what happens.

Best regards 
James

Comment: Thanks James. We have now been able to understand what was causing the actual failure. We are unable to switch context from native to web for our hybrid app. It'd be really helpful if you can take a look at [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=266516).

Thanks!